# How to merge a lot of branches to master at once, is there is any command in git?

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

I have forked someone else's branch in GitHub and he had more than 100 branches. Is there is any way to merge all branches at once to master so that I can view all files at once to master.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Merging has much deeper consequences than viewing. Merging all branches at once is unlikely to make sense. What is your real goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this probably isn't a thing you want to do.  Work on a branch may be very different from the main branch and it may be out of date or otherwise not something you actually want.  I have tons of branches on some projects and tons of them are out of date or just abandoned.

If you're certain you want to do this, you can create a temporary branch and then merge all the branches together that you're interested in with an octopus merge.  Note that octopus merges must be clean; that is, they just fail if they would conflict.  You can do this like so:

```
git checkout -b temp
git merge branch1 branch2 branch3 # and so on
```

If there's a conflict, then you'll have to invoke `git merge` with one branch at a time.